# Add same files to multiple PACKAGES

Tags: linux, yocto, openembedded

I have a the case where three binaries are  in the `/usr/bin` directory and want the test program in a separate package:

```
/usr/bin/execbin1 /usr/bin/execbin2 /usr/bin/test
```

In the recipe file I have specified the PACKAGES I needed in the build,

```
PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN}-custom ${PN} ${PN}-doc ${PN}-dev ${PN}-locale"
```

Now I want to add `/usr/bin/test` in the **${PN}-custom** package. I did the following:

```
FILES_${PN}-custom = "${bindir}/test"
```

Consider the case where I also want to add the same `/usr/bin/test` in the 
**${PN}** Package. I tried the following:

```
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
```

But the generated ${PN} Package had only `execbin1` and `execbin1`.
I need all binaries in the `${PN}` Package.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as i know thats not the default way how to do it so i guess it might be tricky. On the other hand i dont understand why you need once your testprogram within ${PN} and one another not. If Testprogramm is needed, install ${PN}-custom into your image and if it is not needed, simply don't

Comment: I have tried this too, RPROVIDES_${PN} += "${PN}-custom". Still no hope.

Comment: Sidenote not answering your question: If you want to define new package to pick up stuff before `${PN}`, you can use just `PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN += "${PN}-custom"`, so you don't need to modify the default `PACKAGES` variable.

Comment: @TomasNovotny You mean `PACKAGE_BEFORE_${PN} += "${PN}-custom"`. I believe it's the same as `PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN}-custom ${PN} ${PN}-doc ${PN}-dev ${PN}-locale"` ??

Comment: @Sam I mean `PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN`, see https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN . And it is not the same, as ordering in `PACKAGES` matters and your is different. And it is better to not to touch somehow "system" variable (e.g. for maintainability).

Answer (score 3):

Make your normal package (the one without any suffixes) depend on your custom one:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "${PN}-custom"
```

As you described the problem I understand it is a run-time dependency only but the same rationale applies if you need it at build-time dependency (`DEPENDS`), of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the same file in multiple packages.  There's no need: why can't PN depend on PN-custom?

Comment: `RPROVIDES_${PN} += "${PN}-custom"` ?